# Kendo Grid Set Value when checkbox when checked

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, checkbox, kendo-grid

I have code:

```
 <kendo:grid-columns>     
        <kendo:grid-column width="150px" title="<label style='color:white;'>ABC Product</label>" field="productCategory" template="<input type='checkbox' disabled='disabled' value='#=productCategory#' name='test' #=productCategory == true ? 'checked' : ''# />"/> 
        <kendo:grid-column width="auto" title="<label style='color:white;'>Product Name</label>" field="productName"  /> 
        <kendo:grid-column width="110px" title="<label style='color:white;'>Quantity</label>" field="qty" template="<div align='right'>#=kendo.toString(qty,'n0')#</div>"/>  
        <kendo:grid-column width="auto" title="<label style='color:white;'>Unit</label>" field="unit"  />  
        <kendo:grid-column width="140px" title="<label style='color:white;'>Price</label>" field="price" template="<div align='right'>#=kendo.toString(price,'n0')#</div>"/>
        <kendo:grid-column width="170px" title="<label style='color:white;'>Total</label>" field="total" editor="standardGroupEditor" template="<div align='right'>#=kendo.toString(qty*price,'n0')#</div>"/>                         
        <kendo:grid-column width="1px" title="<label style='color:white;display:none'>Total</label>" field="total" editor="standardGroupEditor" template="<input type='hidden' style='text-align:right;width:150px' readonly='readonly' value='#=kendo.toString(qty*price,'n0') #' id='total' name='TEMPVALUE' #=total == null ? '---' : total# />"/>

          <kendo:grid-column title="&nbsp;" width="175px"> 
                <kendo:grid-column-command> 
                  <kendo:grid-column-commandItem name="edit"/> 
                       <kendo:grid-column-commandItem name="delete"/>    
                    </kendo:grid-column-command>  
                 </kendo:grid-column>  
            </kendo:grid-columns>
```

I want to set value "1" on `Unit` when `ABC Product` checked and `null` when unchecked.

I have try this:

```
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function () {

         $(this).prop("checked") ? $("unit").val("1") : $("unit").val(""); });
    }
```

I have learn according to: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26220352/how-to-set-value-of-checkbox-when-checked-and-unchecked-using-ajax-or-jquery) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17141538/kendo-ui-get-id-of-checkbox-when-unchecked) but its nothing happened in my case.

Comment: bxc-> post the complete code . grid and where is your checkbox code and what event you have attached it to

Comment: its already post, see ABC Product carefully, scroll to the right.

Comment: Do you want to change the value in grid column "unit" based on checkbox state ?

Comment: you can do that making use of Change event and then get the uid and based on that use jquery to manipulate the col you want .